# Why isn't font-family working on my navigation links?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a navigation bar with links that seem to ignore my font-family rule. Both colour and size are fine but I can't seem to get the font to change correctly. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="currentpage">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="music.html" class="nav">MUSIC</a></li>
<li><a href="live.html" class="nav">LIVE</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html" class="nav">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#navigation {
margin-top: 20px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#navigation ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#navigation li {
display: inline;
}

a.nav {
display: inline-block;
width: 25%
font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 36px;
text-decoration: none;
}

a.currentpage {
display: inline-block;
width: 25%
font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial;
color: #aa00ff;
font-size: 36px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Why are my other rules fine but font-family is being ignored? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186714/century-gothic-font-usablility-question

Answer (score 1):

The semi-colon is missing from after the previous statement.

That makes it and the font-family statement invalid.

This would have been detected if you had [used a validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: I've been trying all kinds of different possible solutions and I can't believe I missed something as silly as that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add a semicolon** after the width values.

```
a.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.currentpage {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial;
    color: #aa00ff;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

a.nav will select any 'a' elements on your page with a class of "nav". These don't exist so your rules are not taking effect.

I switched this selector to '#navigation a', which matches all items in your #navigation div. (Line 18)

Here's the code:

```
.navigation a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[CodePen with the change](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYZqza)

Your styles are all still there, you just weren't applying them! :)

Comment: "These don't exist"  — Yes, they do.